# How do I get an <audio> tag to close its connection to stream?

Tags: audio, streaming, html5-audio, http-live-streaming, icecast

I am making a web-player for my Icecast2 radio, and what I've noticed is that whenever I pause the playback, the browser doesn't close its connection to the Icecast stream unless the server forcibly closes it (in case of Icecast, that happens if the client falls too far behind on its data queue). That behaviour is really sub-optimal, as it forces the client to fall behind the radio stream and forces the server to do the work it shouldn't have to do, not to mention the listener count being inaccurate.
I did explore my options a little bit. I tried calling .load() on the tag, that reopens the connection. It does kill the old one, but that doesn't achieve the state of there being no active connection. I inadvertently tried destroying the audio tag and making a new one, but that doesn't close any connections (is that a bug?).
I did not yet try switching between multiple sources. If that does the trick, I'll write my own answer unless anyone beats me to it. Otherwise, I am open to your suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by removing the `src` attribute.

```
const audio = document.querySelector('audio');
audio.removeAttribute('src');
audio.load();
```

See also:  https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/media.html#best-practices-for-authors-using-media-elements

> I inadvertently tried destroying the audio tag and making a new one, but that doesn't close any connections (is that a bug?).

You should show a code example for how you're destroying that audio element.  I suspect there is a bug in your code.  There used to be a lot of browser bugs around this sort of thing, but that was many years ago.  I suspect those issues have long since been resolved.

Comment: I destroyed and remade the audio tag multiple times while editing elements in browser's Inspector. It would each time cause the listener count reported by the server to go up by one and stay there.

Comment: What's on your network tab?  Did it show as still having a connection?

Comment: I don't think it showed it as terminated. I am not entirely sure, I might have a closer look later.

Comment: Yeah, so removing an audio tag via Inspector doesn't make it close its connection. The browser is Firefox 86.0.1.

Comment: I've also encountered a little issue with the suggested approach. There needs to be a delay between assigning the src value and executing .play() on some systems. Namely, I've had this problem on an iPad Mini running iOS 9.3.5. I am thus using setTimeout with a delay of 100ms for both .play() and .load() whenever I change the source.

Comment: I would also suggest setting src to "data:," instead. I believe emptying the attribute ends up pointing it at the website's root, not sure about removing it. And the delay actually needs to have more of an awaiting behavior if anything...